# Is there an m2e view for running selected Maven run configs with a single click?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2e

In my current project we have 30+ Maven run configurations.

Are any of you aware of a plugin that contributes a view for Eclipse where I can see all/a selected set of Maven run configurations and run them with a single click?

It is a bit cumbersome to always go to *Run -> Run configurations... ->* scroll a year and search the required configuration and run it.

Run faviourites are not an options since 1) I have tons of important configurations there already and 2) spamming it with all the required maven configurations would eat all the screen up :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues suggested trying the [Eclipse Runner](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-runner) plug-in (easy to install through the marketplace).

Simple and perfect for the job, here's a screenshot:

[image]